# full background image that scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background, slideshow

I'm using supersized ( http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ ) for a full size image background slideshow, but I need the background image to scroll as the user scrolls up/down to read text.

The site i'm using as a reference is http://www.samsung.com/latin/
They used flash for the background slideshow.

Is there any way to achieve the same with js?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick, I'm using it myself:

```
#supersized {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    }
```

Using ***position:relative*** as others have suggested won't work, nor will using ***position:absolute*** by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not filmier with Supersized, but taking a look at the [demo site](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.1/demo.html), it appears to be a simple CSS problem. Try changing `#supersized`  from `position: fixed;` to `position:relative;`

Comment: Hi, That's the first thing I tried, it only causes the slideshow to disappear

Answer (score 0):

If you change `#superzised` from `position:fixed;` to `position:absolute;` you should get a scrolling image.